# Filter trough array of objects - result of new returned array is not expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Problem is in filter() trough array of objects, I need to check does currenlty `index(object)` of array have property with value  `isTransffered: false`.

Here is how I use filter function:

```
let filteredResults = allResults

// isTransferred --> coming from state and have value "false"
if (isTransferred && isTransferred !== 'all') {
  filteredResults = filteredResults.filter(
    res => res.isTransfer === isTransferred
  )
}
```

`filteredResults` is array of objects - here is first index of array:

```
0:
 accountNumber: "8787986"
 isTransfer: true
 jurisdiction: "AK"
 lineOfBusiness: "wc"
```

I need to check does isTransfer is false.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `res => res.isTransfer === !isTransferred` ?

Comment: Maybe this conditon in IF state is problem: (isTransferred && isTransferred !== 'all')
isTransferred is false

Comment: Can you please tell what is `typeof(isTransferred)`? if it is `boolean` then you should write condition as `if (isTransferred.toString() && isTransferred.toString() !== 'all') {`.

Comment: isTransferred can be: true / false or 'all'  I need to filer trough array based on isTransffered array, if is fasle return all objects from array which have isTranssfferred value false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your condition in if

```
if (isTransferred && isTransferred !== 'all') {
  // this will not be executed if isTransferred is false
  filteredResults = filteredResults.filter(
    res => res.isTransfer === isTransferred
  )
}
```

Simply write it like

```
if (isTransferred !== 'all') {
  filteredResults = filteredResults.filter(
    res => res.isTransfer === isTransferred
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If inside `filteredResults` you need to have all the object having the property `isTransfer === false`, then you have a problem in the `filter()` callback.

If you enter the `IF` statement, then `isTransferred` is equal to `true`. Though, in the `filter()` callback you write: `res => res.isTransfer === isTransferred`, which, in common language means *"take the entries which have property `isTransfer` equal to `isTransferred`"*.
Though, since we are in the `IF`, `isTransferred` is equal to `true`! So you are just taking the entries that have `isTrasnfer` property equal to `true`.

Solution: you should write `res => res.isTransfer !== isTransferred`, our simpler `res => res.isTransfer === false`